# Media query for PHP variables

Tags: php, html, css, media-queries

I have two PHP variables:

1. `$video_mp4`: Which is a video file.
2. `$video_poster`: Which is an image.

For desktop, I want `$video_mp4` to load as an ambient video, which it does. But on `max-width: 576px` I want the `$video_poster` to show.

Unsure on how to approach this though. This is my current code and thought process:

```html
<div class="hero__container--teaser">
  <div class="hero__teaser">
    <!-- By default, show video -->
    <?php echo wp_video_shortcode(  $video_mp4 );  ?>
    <!-- If max-width 576px, show image -->
    <?php echo "<img src='$video_poster'>;" ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Wondering what the best practise here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap video content with `.video` and image content with  `.image` and using CSS [Media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) in `max-width: 576px` show image and hide video

```css
.hero__teaser .image {
  display: none;
}
@media (max-width: 576px) {
  .hero__teaser .image {
    display: block !important;
  }
  .hero__teaser .video {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="hero__container--teaser">
  <div class="hero__teaser">
    <div class="video">
      <?php echo wp_video_shortcode(  $video_mp4 );  ?>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      <?php echo "<img src='$video_poster'>;" ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```